# Using multiple factor scores as a dependent variable

Tags: factor-analysis

I'm researching the impact of unconditional cash transfers on the treated households using observational data.

It's very common in the literature to construct indices for you dependent variable. For example, one of the dimensions that you'd want to assess is health. My data contains questions such as:
1. Have you been ill in the past 2 weeks?
2. Have you been ill in the past year?
3. Did you visit a doctor?
(Most of them are yes-no binary questions)

Similarly for other dimensions such as assets:
1. Do you live in a house made out of clay?
2. Do you have clean source of water?
3. Do you have source of electricity?
(Most of them are yes-no binary questions)

There are other dimensions in which the questions asked are not binary in response. Specifically in consumption and expenditure related questions, where the answers are in monetary values, which I'd also like to construct and index for.

Optimally, what I want is to create an index that groups the variables in each dimension.

My questions:

1. Is factor analysis (FA) suitable to combine the variables for each dimension? Are there any suggestions other than FA?
2. Generally, apart from my explained setup, if I did apply the factor analysis and it resulted in 2 factor scores, how can I use them as a **dependent** variable? Do I need to combine them and hence I'd standardize and add them?

Any reference or stata codes are highly appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: You can take a look here: (pdf) for a discussion on using factors scores in regression (see in particular Table 1, 3rd column, for the case of independent variable observed, dependent variable factor scores)